# Can I configure a table such that inserted rows always have a greater primary key

Tags: postgresql

I would like to configure a table in Postgres to behave like an append only log. This table will have an automatically generated primary ID.

Workers will work on the items in the table in order and should only need to store the last row ID that they have completed.

How can i prevent rows being written to the table (perhaps by some transactions taking longer than others) where the row ID is less than the greatest value in the table?

Comment: That's the very definition of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column: every new record will be assigned the next available record number.

Comment: Except the numbers assigned are session specific, so a session that starts earlier but lasts longer can write to the table with an id that less then one that started later but finished sooner.

Comment: What's the point in having multiple workers if they must finish strictly in sequence?

Comment: @Bergi each worker consumes the whole log but does a different task, they are completely independent. I just need to make sure that, between reads, a log message is never inserted before the last one

Comment: @TomC Why do the workers consume the log at all, isn't the log only for recording the worker results? Where do the workers get their work from, and how do they ensure that they are working on different tasks? What exactly do you mean by "between reads"?

Comment: "*How can i prevent*" - are you trying to add database constraints that make it impossible for a malicious actor to insert wrong data, or are the workers cooperative and you're only worried about race conditions?

Comment: @Bergi event sourcing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prevent concurrent inserts in the table (short of locking the table, which is a bad idea, because it breaks autovacuum).

So there is no way to to guarantee that rows are inserted in a certain order. The order in which rows are inserted isn't really a meaningful concept in PostgreSQL.

If you really want that, you have to use a different mechanism to serialize inserts, for example using PostgreSQL advisory locks or synchronization mechanisms on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Except the numbers assigned are session specific, so a session that starts earlier but lasts longer can write to the table with an id that is less then one that started later but finished sooner. So either you create your own number sequence generation that involves locking or you use an INSERT timestamp.